# Linked list partition around value clarification

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've been practicing different interview problems and I came across a problem that I can't seem to resolve when stepping through the code by hand.

The problem is to write a function that partitions a linked list around a value `x` such that all nodes less than `x` come before all the nodes great than or equal to `x`.

[3, 5, 8, 5, 10, 2 ,1] where x=5

Should output something like: [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5, 10] (output can vary depending on implementation).

Here's the solution:

```
LinkedListNode* partition(LinkedListNode* node, int x)
{
    LinkedListNode* head = node;
    LinkedListNode* tail = node;

    while (node)
    {
         LinkedListNode* next = node->next;
         if (node->data < x)
         {
             node->next = head;
             head = node;
         } else {
             tail->next = node;
             tail = node;
         }
         node = next;
     }
     tail->next = nullptr;
     return head;
}
```

I know the solution works and when run on the linked list above, I get the following output: [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5, 10]

When I run through this by hand, I get confused.  When first iterating through the linked list, `node`, `head`, `tail` all point towards the node that has the value of 3.  Now we're in the `if` statement.

We set `node->next` to `head`, which now points to itself (the one with node->data = 3)!  After iterating through the entire list, this node's next field always points to itself.

Clearly, this function is working as intended but I must be stepping through it wrong.  Any insight into what I'm overlooking??

Thanks!

edit: clarification

Comment: You get next variable set before changing value of node->next - so you follow the old link, not the changed link

Comment: Ah, I see, the first node's `next` field is always pointing to head which will move to different nodes as long as the `if` condition is met.  Thanks for talking it out with me!

Comment: Use a binary tree.  A binary tree is a subset of linked lists.

Comment: You could make two lists, one for numbers smaller than 5 and the other for numbers greater than or equal to 5.  Next, append the large list to the small list.  The sublists just need a "push" functionality.

Comment: There is one error. If an empty list is given, then `tail->next = nullptr` fails.